# ConTeXt with LuaTeX to compile mathml

Tags: luatex, context

I am using ConTeXt with LuaTeX to compile mathml. I would like to change the MathML fonts to a OTF Font. Please advice how this could be done. I have included a sample code below.

```
\usemodule[mathml]
\usemodule[newmml]
\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]
\usemodule[simplefonts][size=10pt]
\setmainfont[Futura]
\setsansfont[Helvetica]
\setmonofont[Helvetica]
\starttext
This is sample text
\xmlprocessdata{}{
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
<mrow>
<mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi>
</mrow>
</math>
}{}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be easiest to do afterwards via CSS?

Comment: Which version of ConTeXt are you using (see output of `context --version`)? The above example works fine for me (with ConTeXt MkIV 2014.04.24).

Comment: Or is the question simply asking how to use Opentype Math fonts?

Comment: I am using ConTeXt MkIV, the opentype mathfont is not applied to the math equations when I compile and create pdf. I like to know the macro to apply the fonts for math equations

Comment: You have not set an math font! Use \setmathfont[...] to set the math font. By the way, in recent versions of context, the functionality of the simpleslides module is now part of te core, but with a slightly different syntax

Answer (score 3):

The [`simplefonts`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/simplefonts) module has been superseded by [`\definefontfamily`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfamily).  The `newmml` module is MkII-only and just loads the `mathml` module in MkIV.

Because I don't own any of the proprietary typefaces in your question I substituted Futura with Open Sans and Helvetica with TeX Gyre Heros.  To show that Unicode math fonts work well, I selected TeX Gyre Pagella Math.

```
\usemodule[mathml]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [Open Sans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [TeX Gyre Heros]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [tt] [TeX Gyre Heros]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]
\starttext
This is sample text
\xmlprocessdata{}{
  <math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
  <mrow>
  <mi>a</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi>
  </mrow>
  </math>
}{}
\stoptext
```

[image]